# Java: Why does my book start concatenating string vars with concatenation with an empty string, specifically using System.out.print()?

Tags: java, string, concatenation

While reading my school's assigned book for Java I keep seeing string concatenation starting with an empty string.
Specifically, I've only seen it when concatenating string variables in `System.out.print*()` statements (where * is "" or"ln").
I have tried searching for a reason to no avail; I suspect that my wording is off.

An example from my book is: `System.out.println("" + stringVar + anotherStringVar);`

While near the end of the book I found the following:

> To ensure printing of characters, start your print statement as: `System.out.println("" + ...`

In yet another part of my book I found `System.out.print(num1 + " + " + num2 + " is " + (num1 + num2));` which seems to violate its own rule.

Why does my book recommend doing this? Why does it seemingly ignore this rule sometimes?

Comment: it might be a convention of author, but no java rule exists for this kind of syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your book is going a little overboard trying to avoid the complex rules that decide when `+` means concatenation and when it means addition. As an exercise, compare the following outputs:

```
System.out.println(1 + 2);
System.out.println("" + 1 + 2);
```

**EDIT:** Just noticed the quote about ensuring "printing of characters". Is that by any chance referring to the `char` data type? That's a particularly confusing scenario to look out for, since `char` is actually a numeric data type. See what happens when you replace 1 and 2 with 'a' and 'b' in the above example.

Comment: Ah, I can see where this is good to be explicit. The book also does this with char variables, which is also understandable, but why does it pertain to string variables?

Comment: @CupricWolf There's no reason to. That's why I suggested they're being overly cautious.